# Regular Expression to replace a bracket with word in front when not preceded by word

Tags: php, regex

I am facing problem with a regular expression.

I have a string like `('A'&'B')`

Now I want to convert it to `CONCAT('A'&'B')` which is simple and I have done using

```
str_replace("(", "CONCAT(", $subject)
```

But I want to replace `"("` to `"CONCAT("` if the string doesn't have prior string `"extract_json_value"`.

So I don't want to replace `extract_json_value('A'&'B')` to `extract_json_valueCONCAT('A'&'B')` but it will stay as it is `extract_json_value('A'&'B')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand your regex with a negative lookbehind:

```
(?<!extract_json_value)\(
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/bS8nF8/2)!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to do this.

```
if (strpos($subject, '(') === 0) {
  $subject = str_replace('(', 'CONCAT(', $subject);
}
```

If your string contains other text you can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and use a word boundary `\B` for this.

```
$subject = preg_replace('/\B\(/', 'CONCAT(', $subject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookbehind in order to match a group not preceded by a string.

First, let's have a regexp matching all strings but those containing "extract_json_value":

```
(?<!extract_json_value).*
```

Now, let's use preg_replace

```
$string = "extract_json_value('A'&'B')";
$pattern = '/^(?<!extract_json_value)(\(.+\))$/';
$replacement = 'CONCAT\1';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
// prints out "extract_json_value('A'&'B')"
```

It works too with

```
$string = "('A'&'B')";
...
// prints out "CONCAT('A'&'B')"
```

However, it does not work with

```
$string = "hello('A'&'B')";
...
// prints out "helloCONCAT('A'&'B')"
```

So, continue with a `preg_replace_callback`:
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-replace-callback.php